# Get index of list of map from map

Tags: flutter, dart

How do you get index of list of maps from a map. I tried to use `indexOf` which works but by the time the position of values are mixed up then it returns -1.

**UPDATE:** It actually doesn't work even in right order

```
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = [{'id':1, 'name':'a'}, {'id':2, 'name':'b'}];
  Map<String, dynamic> item = {'name':'a','id':1}; //<- position name and id are in different places

  print(list.indexOf(item)); // so it return -1
```

The best way would be to get index of list where item contains same id ... if you know what I mean... How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `indexWhere` instead `indexOf`.

```
Map<String, dynamic> item = {'name':'a','id':1};
print(list.indexWhere((i) => i['id'] == item['id'])); // prints 0
```

```
Map<String, dynamic> item = {'name':'b','id':2};
print(list.indexWhere((i) => i['id'] == item['id'])); // prints 1
```

Comment: Wow... I kinda missed the `indexWhere`... Thank you very much.. you saved my day :)